# Limit Safecracker access to specific entries, using member groups and categories

Tags: safecracker, zoo-visitor

I'm wondering about best practice, and if I'm setting myself up for trouble.

**The goal**:
Limit an editor's Safecracker access to specific entries within a channel, based on the member group of the editor.

**The setup**:
I'm using Zoo Visitor for members as channel entries. Thinking of using categories to limit Safecracker access within a channel.

**An example**:
my_member_channel has an entry named Dan, who is in my_editors member group. Dan needs to be able to edit other users in the my_member_channel that have the category "Editor Category" selected, but no others.

**This seems to work:**

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="my_member_channel" limit="1"}

    {categories}

        {if category_id == 1 && (member_group == '6' || member_group == '8')}
            {!-- 
                If the category "Editor Category" (1) is selected, and the logged in user is in my_standard_admin (6) or my_editors (8) member group. 
                --}

            {exp:safecracker 
                channel="my_member_channel" 
                entry_id="{segment_3}" 
            }

                Various fields in the channel to be edited here,
                including a Matrix field with a Playa column:
                {field:my_matrix_field}

                submit button
            {/exp:safecracker}          

        {/if}

    {/categories}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I tested this lightly, but it seems to work fine. So if I continue down this route I'll create "pseudo member categories" to be used in various channels and then conditionally check before showing the Safecracker form.

**Am I missing a much more stable approach?** I would prefer doing this all using the CP, but can't seem to work out a way to dole out the permissions in a custom enough way, therefore Safecracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wouldn't wrap safecracker inside a channel:entries tag. Fields like title, url_title etc. might collide. You can use an embed with safecracker (pass thru data) or use stash to capture info from the other channel first, and stash:get inside safecracker to show/hide information.

If there are multiple categories assigned, you might also want to limit the output of the {categories} tag with show="" and limit="" parameters:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories-tag-pair-parameters

Comment: Appreciate the help and good advice. So using categories (+ member groups) for safecracker permissions isn't crazy?

Comment: Nope, not crazy. By default there is no fine grained access control in EE. A member (group) can either publish entries in a channel or not, and can edit entries published by others or not. There's also an add-on called Entry-access