# Allow multiple (assigned) members / authors to edit an entry

Tags: safecracker, channel-form, author

Currently i use safecracker in combination with author_only="yes" to allow members to publish and edit their own news and edit their info page.

**What would be a method / procedure or what would you suggest to allow

multiple members to edit one specific entry (e.g. the info page)?**

- I can't just only remove the author_only parameter and allow all members to edit all info pages. Only assigned members should be able to edit an entry.
- Is a relationship/playa field on the info-page a possible route? How would you check for access-privileges?

---

**Edit:** one approach is with categories but this gives more broad access to editors.
[Limit Safecracker access to specific entries, using member groups and categories](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9823/limit-safecracker-access-to-specific-entries-using-member-groups-and-categories?rq=1)

---

**Edit2:**
Possible solution, using a modified version of chosen_member addon
(e.g. added a method to check if logged in user is selected)

```
{exp:channel entries url_title="segment_3" }
  {if chosen_member_field:is_chosen=="yes"}
    {embed="group/safecracker" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Where do you want to store the list of the members who will have access to the entries? In the entry itself or in a member group? Or in a global vars?

Comment: with the solution from edit2, it would be stored in the entry itself. i'm trying to avoid creating lots of member groups. A dedicated category group could be an option, but there are no member select custom fields for categories.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. You have to make a 2 steps verification:

```
{!-- Ensure user is logged in --}
{if logged_out}
    {redirect="/login"}
{/if}
{!-- Check if user can view this entry --}
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="mychannel"
    disable="custom_fields|categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    dynamic="off"
    require_entry="yes"
}
    {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
    {exp:pvl_checkif value="{member_id}" is_not_in="{authorized_members}"}{redirect="/unauthorised"}{/exp:pvl_checkif}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{safecracker....}
```

{authorized_members} is your field containing members list. It should be pipe delimited, or you can use an other delimiter and specify it an the delimiter="" parameter of pvl_checkif.

See the [doc of pvl_checkif here](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pvl-check-if).

Comment: Nice solution. Note: When not using low- or mo-variables, or my globalmembers plugin, the {if logged_out} is parsed late, and channel entries is still parsed. Note2: inside channel:entries {member_id} is {author_id}, using {logged_in_member_id} gives plugin value a string (e.g. parsed late). Note3. safecracker tag is called before your plugin (and thus before redirect), i like to avoid that (csrf hole).

Comment: Concerning logged_out, I'm not sure, maybe with ifelse plugin from Mark Croxton (https://github.com/croxton/Ifelse). You can use {else} tag inside pvl_checkif to avoid safecracker parsing. For {logged_in_member_id}, http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables. That makes a lot of addons, but it should work.